# Is a switch function supposed to change the array I am trying to duplicate into another array with minor changes?

Tags: arrays, c, function, switch-statement, escaping

I am learning through K&R book and doing an exercise where I'm supposed to copy one array into another with minor changes (converting escape strings into the actual signs and letters) using a switch function `escape(from,to)`.

It seems that I did it alright, but what is puzzling me is that the array (from) is being changed as well into a few letters. I was wondering why is this happening and if am I not informed enough about switch or something else?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 250

int main()
{
    char ar1[MAX];
    char ar2[MAX];
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if ( i < MAX - 1 ){
            ar1[i] = c;
            i++;}
        else
            ar1[i++] = '\0';
    }

    escape(ar1,ar2);
    printf("%s",ar2);
    printf("%s",ar1);

    return 0;
}

escape(char s[],char t[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i < MAX )
    {
        switch(s[i])
        {
        case '\n':
            t[j] = '\\';
            j++;
            t[j++] = 'n';
            i++;
            break;

        default:
            t[j] = s[i];
            i++;
            j++;
            break;

        }
    }
    t[j] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Your input loop is never checking that you are not exceeding `MAX` characters.

Comment: `escape` doesn't have a prototype.

Comment: Also the input loop will not terminate the string if the input is shorter than `MAX`.

Comment: Would you mind to provide some input and output example? -- You might want to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: My problem is not the input loop , i know its not perfect and its not meant to be. i Checked the ar1[] before and after the use of the function, my question is why is the ar1[] get changed AFTER i use the escape function. i know i should have put void before escape function , but again its not the problem. im asking why does the ar1[] change?

Comment: the changes that occur in ar1[] are basically that the whole ar1[] becomes empty , and have only 1 or 2 elements remaining which are the last 1 or 2 elements of NOW ar2[] , i hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

K&R is outdated, as is the version of C found inside it, called C90. This old version allowed various language flaws like "implicit int" and "no prototype functions". What happens in this old version when you type `escape(ar1,ar2);` with no prior function declaration visible, is that the compiler "takes a chance" at the types used - specifically it assumes that everything has type `int`.

In your case the C90 compiler find's the call `escape(ar1,ar2);` then goes: "Oh boy what's `escape`, never heard of it before. It's probably an `int escape (int, int)` function, right? Lets do that and see if there will be fireworks".

While in reality it should have been `void escape (char s[],char t[])` for your program to function as intended.

Similarly, when you type `escape(char s[],char t[])` then it is implicitly assumed that this function returns `int`, which is not what you want.

You can get rid of all these problems by updating to the current standard C and also find a less outdated book. In standard C, your code isn't allowed to compile and there will be no strange surprises.

Regardless of C version, you can fix the problem by providing a prototype-format (types present) function declaration:

```
void escape (char s[], char t[]); // function declaration, prototype format

int main()
{
  ...
}

void escape (char s[], char t[]) // function definition
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop in your `escape` function will always overrun the bounds of the output array.  Even if there are no newlines to escape,   the final `t[j] = '\0';` will do that because you unconditionally run `MAX` iterations of the loop and therefore increment `j` at least `MAX` times.  Undefined behavior results, of which unexpected modifications to other variables is one reasonably common manifestation.

You structure the input array as a string, so probably `escape` should stop converting data when it reaches the string terminator.  To be completely safe, however, it must also be sure terminate when it fills up the output array if it does that before processing all the input (and don't forget to leave room for the output's string terminator).